# FingerPrint Authentication on server side Ionic

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3

I am trying to link the `FingerPrint Authentication` with the user in API/Data base, something like a token that we can compare to authorize in some parts of my application.

**Android Example**:
In android I am using this plugin: `@ionic-native/android-fingerprint-auth`

The return of fingerprint authentication success is a json like this:

```
{
 token: "TOKEN CODE"
 withBackup: true
}
```

On Android the Token always changes when I authenticate again. So it’s not possible to compare with the token saved on API.

**IOS Example**:
In Iphone I am using thig plugin: `@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio`

The return of fingerprint authentication success is a string like this:

Success
In IOS, they don't give me any token or key to link the account user.

**Question:** 
Is there a way to link account with the fingerprint? To allow user to login with the fingerprint on app?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible, the native SDKs don't provide any information about the fingerprint, probably because of privacy, they just make sure that the fingerprint read by your app/plugin matches with one of the registered on the device.

Comment: There is any topic in apple/android websites talking about it?  I need to show that to my client.

Comment: For iOS https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/ `To maximize security, your app never gains access to any of the underlying authentication data.`